# Guardar en un fichero la salida de un comando en C

Tags: c, windows, powershell

estoy intentado guardar en un fichero la salida de un comando que ejecuto de powerShell en C, el resultado sale por terminal, me crea el fichero pero no almacena nada en él

¿qué faltaría hacer para que lo almacene?
He intentado con la siguiente linea:

`system("start powershell.exe Get-DnsClientServerAddress >dns2.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Sí, el resultado de ese comando se imprime en el archivo `dns2.txt`.

Específicamente de **start powershell.exe Get-DnsClientServerAddress**. No de la parte que te interesa que es **Get-DnsClientServerAddress**.

Lo que puedes hacer es encerrar entre comillas el comando que debe ejecutar. Así:

```
powershell.exe "Get-DnsClientServerAddress > dns2.txt"
```

O si lo prefieres con [`OutFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file):

```
powershell.exe "Get-DnsClientServerAddress | Out-File dns2.txt"
```

En C necesitas escapar las comillas. Así:

```
system("powershell.exe \"Get-DnsClientServerAddress > dns2.txt\"");
```

---

Por cierto, aunque pueda ser más simple esa no es la mejor solución. Idealmente deberías usar las funciones del sistema. Puedes consultar las de Windows en [la documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/).

La pregunta es más sobre comandos de consola. Así que si te interesa, apuesto a que las funciones que necesitas están [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_dns/).